# promise all to get data and merge

Tags: javascript, promise

I am trying to execute two API requests in parallel and merge the response values into a single variable. My attempt is as below:

```
const [a, b] = await Promise.All([
    API.getOne(),
    API.getTwo(),
]);
const c = a.concat(b);
console.log(c);
```

When I print `c`, it is not printed. But in the network tab I can see APIs are being called fine and the data comes. But I can see anything after `promise.all()` is not executed. How can I fix this issue?

Comment: Does both API calls return arrays?

Comment: yes both of returns array when I checked the network tab I could see

Comment: when I change promise.All to promise.all it works. thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a syntax error, it has to be `Promise.all`.

See the [MDN reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all)